# I am using iframe which is using ajax tech. and it does not resize height while on fly

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, height

I am using iframe in my website for which i am using **doIframe()** to resize the height it works fine when page loads but my iframe is using ajax technique. When it load some new data this function do not resize the window and content at the end of iframe do not show.

I want you to update this function (or suggest a New Function) which resize the iframe and monitor it while the frame is running.

**I tried many other jquery functions but so for not working for me please help**
**I tried "change" event instead of "load" event but did not work out**

```
(function() {
    function doIframe() {
        o = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
        for (i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            if (/\bautoHeight\b/.test(o[i].className)) {
                setHeight(o[i]);
                addEvent(o[i], 'load', doIframe);
            }
        }
    }

    function setHeight(e) {
        if (e.contentDocument) {
            e.height = e.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 35;
        } else {
            e.height = e.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        }
    }

    function addEvent(obj, evType, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
            return true;
        } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            var r = obj.attachEvent("on" + evType, fn);
            return r;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById && document.createTextNode) {
        addEvent(window, 'load', doIframe);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you load the new content? If you click some buttons to load content, you can consider calling a function to resize iframe on the event of click.

Comment: Yes i am using a button but code this code is in parent file but button is in child (iframe) file. how can i access parent function from child on click event. please suggest me how i am not very good at jquery

Comment: You can call parent functions as long as both frames are on the same domain, e.g. `document.parent.foo();`

Answer (score 1):

In the parent page, you can add an event listener to the iframe content which will listen any click in the body of content inside iframe. For example running this function once can handle this.

```
function boyutAyarlayici() {
    var cerceveIci = document.getElementById("your_iframe_id")
                             .contentWindow.document.body;
    setHeight(cerceveIci);
    if (cerceveIci.addEventListener) { //if not IE
        cerceveIci.addEventListener('click', function () {
            setHeight(cerceveIci);
        }, false);
    }
    else if (cerceveIci.attachEvent) { //if IE
        cerceveIci.attachEvent('onclick', function () {
            setHeight(cerceveIci);
        });
    }
}
```

where my setHeight function is like this:

```
function setHeight(cerceveIci) {
    //find the height of the internal page
    var the_height = cerceveIci.scrollHeight;

    //change the height of the iframe
    document.getElementById("your_iframe_id").height = the_height;
}
```

Then, if you click anything in the iframe, iframe will be resized to fit the content.

Comment: If you think that resizing occurs before content loads, you can also set timer to run setHeight() function after some time, eg. when you are sure that content is loaded. Not an elegant way but works.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have three pages:

- **mainPage.html** which contains iframe.
- **framedPage.html** which is shown in the iframe by src attribute of iframe.
- **loadMe.html** which will be loaded into framedPage.html page by $.load() function.

In the loadMe.html which you load with ajax, you can write some jQuery code in head section of the page to call resizing function when document is loaded:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        parent.setHeight();
    });
</script>
```

In the mainPage.html, which contains iframe, you can write a javascript function in the head of the page to resize iframe:

```
function setHeight(cerceveIci) {
    //find the height of the internal page
    var the_height = cerceveIci.scrollHeight;

    //change the height of the iframe
    document.getElementById("your_iframe_id").height = the_height;
}
```

So, when loadMe.html is loaded in framedPage.html successfully, setHeight() function of mainPage.html is called and iframe resizes.

As to how to load something into framedPage.html, you can add some jQuery function into head of framedPage.html:

```
function loadWithAjax() {
    $("#myDiv").load("loadMe.html");
});
```

and call it with a link `<a onclick="loadWithAjax();">Load with Ajax.</a>`.